# Where can I find raccoons?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

In order to upgrade my equipment, I need some raccoon skins. I've been playing quite awhile, and while I already hunted 60 boars, 40 foxes and 20 rabbits, raccoons elude me. I managed to only hunt down 6 of them, and since they do not always drop the needed skin, it's quite a grind.

Where to consistently find raccoons in Horizon Zero Dawn?

Answer (score 9):

According to the comments on this video, this is a pretty consistent spot to find a raccoon if you circle around the rock after killing one.

The location is near the southwestern corner of the map in the Sacred Lands side of the map, I believe.

It doesn't seem like a very quick thing to farm, but if I remember correctly, you only need a couple of raccoon skins in the entire game.

Comment: I was also able to find many of them near Meridian.

Comment: As a side note, I found more Raccoons around night time, which would make sense considering they're nocturnal in our world. Could have been coincidence, but this was the case for multiple nighttime strolls.

Comment: This answer does not work later in the game, see comments on the [original YouTube video](https://youtu.be/PHtCIiVyjoY). (Example: *"Doesn't work in post game. No creatures will spawn in this area due to what happens near the end of the game, so there are only 2 Watchers just past where the raccoon is in the video, and behind the rock at the start are 2-3 Scrappers."*)

Comment: I could not find in this location in PS4 when level 25

Answer (score 4):

Raccoons can be found in the bottom left of the map, see this image:

[image: Raccoons be here]

And zoomed in:

[image: Zoomed in on raccoons]

There are a variety of animals here:

- boars
- foxes
- geese
- rabbits
- **raccoons**
- rats
- turkeys

In the river nearby are trout and salmon.

The location shown is fairly free of machines. However, in the vicinity (particularly to the west) are dangerous machines including [Stalkers](https://horizonzerodawn.fandom.com/wiki/Stalker) and a [Stormbird](https://horizonzerodawn.fandom.com/wiki/Stormbird).

And you will need to be patient. Keep looking for raccoons using your focus. Then mark them to track. They respawn eventually.

Comment: I confirm that this is the right location to find raccoon. I could not find anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I Googled for many Racoon sites, here's what I learned:
 - Good places are with trees, forest
 - Better at night then daylight
 - I hunted down alltogether 29 Racoons, when I finally got my last needed Racoon Skin to upgrade my Potions Pouch to the max

My stats to max out all carry pouches:
Boar 60, Rat 10, Rabbit 30, Racoon 29, Goose 4, Fox 64, Salmon 14, Turkey 48,   Trout 13

Answer (score -3):

Maybe it depends on the stage of the game but I found Sigma to be a good raccoon spot.

Answer (score -4):

I found a lot near Cauldron Stigma.